# Windows Restore Point but no need to keep new files

Tags: windows, windows-10, system-restore

**Hello, so my problem is** that I have a program, when I open it, it creates files/registry on my PC that are hidden (I can't spot them with any program, and please don't suggest me a program to watch files/registry being created on my PC, because the program has high security for these purposes)

**What I need is** to format my PC, add my files and programs that I always need, then use a program to save or "create restore point" then I open the program that will create "traces" that I don't need to keep, use it for my needs then when I want the hidden files/registry to be deleted, I simply go back to the restore point or backup, then I'll have my PC with the exact files/registry (ONLY) that I had when I created the restore point.

I have tried this with windows restore point but it doesn't work for my needs, because it will keep all new files created after the restore point. (I think it will keep all new registries too)

Please tell me a program or method that can do my needs
Thank you so much!

Comment: What is is the name of the program you are running?

Comment: It's private software, individual person made it

Comment: @DavidPostill (I don't know if I have to ping you to receive a notification)

Comment: Find out what you need from the individual who mad the program. All anyone else could do is guess.

Comment: You guys asking me personal questions that I cannot answer, I just need a solution please

Comment: If yiou do not know, make sure you know where you programs are, back up personal data, run a Windows 10 Repair Install and use the option to keep only data, Then when that is done, install only programs you know, That will work.

Comment: Solution posted. Please acknowledge.

Answer (score 1):

> Please tell me a program or method that can do my needs Thank you so
> much!

I read through all the posts. You need to learn what a Windows 10 Repair Install is.

Go to the Windows Media Creation link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  When you get to the spot where it asks what to keep, select the option to Keep Only Data.

Allow it to finish and then install your programs.

Two things:  1. This will work - I have done it.  and 2. Your data and Windows User Profile will be kept, but back up important documents anyway.

This is how to repair your computer in this case.

The above process will remove software associated with the files above. That should be good enough (just data files do not cause issues).

If, however, you wish to get rid of everything associated with this software including it files, then you need to back up completely, run the Repair process, and select the option to Keep Nothing. This is essentially a fresh install.

Comment: Thanks, but this will keep the custom files ("traces") that I don't need them to be kept. They will be considered personal data too

Comment: Keep Everything keeps all data (so long as not forcefully kept in Program Files or Windows). You can delete what you do not need first, or after the repair.

Comment: Thing is like I said, I don't know the location of the files that I must delete

Comment: If you really need to get rid of the files (you may not need to since the software will be gone) then you need to back up all you need and use the option to Keep Nothing. That is a fresh install.

Comment: Yep that's what I do, that's not a good option for me tho, I would like not to format/reset :/

Comment: I appreciate this, but since you do not have sufficient knowledge of this unknown software, deleting the software (all software) via Keep Data will keep only the data associated with the software. Data on its own does not do anything (bad) so no harm keeping just that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128595/discussion-between-clinkz-mta-and-john).